# Loading page content inside Div with Ajax not working inside modal window

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-window

I have a page which displays team members (each being a custom post type) and, when a team member is clicked, the content opens inside a modal window called #single-post-container. I do this by attaching an onclick event to each link which has a class of ".post-link". This works fine, but inside the modal window I also have links allowing the navigation between members without closing the window. I display these using `<?php previous_post_link(); ?>` (same for next post) and I made sure the links being output also have the class ".post-link" by using a filter inside functions.php. The problem is that these links don't always work, sometimes the page content doesn't load inside the modal windows and I suspect there is something not right in my apropach even though it works most of the time.

Here is the relevant code:

The modal window div, which is initially hidden:

```
<div id="single-post-container" class="hidden"></div>
```

The links where jQuery will attach the "onclick" event:

```
<h1><a class="post-link" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

The ajax.js script which I enqueue after jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
        $("#single-post-container").show();
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#single-post-container").html("content loading");
        $("#single-post-container").load(post_link);
    return false;
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("#single-post-container").hide();
    });
});
```

And then in the template for each single post called single-team.php, I also call the same script at the end, since I know the links generated within are not part of the DOM at the beginning, so the event listener cannot be attached until the page is loaded inside the modal window (though I suspect this is where my approach might be wrong):

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you have working fiddle fot this query?

Comment: There may be an issue with event binding with an html element

Comment: I am doing this in Wordpress - Should I post the complete content of my template files? I'm not sure how to build a fiddle that is relevant to the situation, but I'd be happy to do so.

I'm not sure if I am using Ajax the way it is supposed to be used. But in about 90% of times the event is binding to the links and the content is loading, only sometimes it fails to load.

By the way this is the test site where I am trying to do this:
http://pasidevindecare.ro/despre/

Comment: Please apply $(".post-link").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){});

Comment: $("#close").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){});

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I understand correctly I shuld apply unbind to both $(".post-link") and $("#close")? I did that, and it appears to solve the problem. I'll report back once I make sure there are no more instances when the content fails to load.

Comment: does it resolve your issue?

Comment: I believe so. I don't know how to check and I'm not even sure I am using Ajax the way it is supposed to be used, but so far I haven't had any more issues with the content not loading. I would have voted your answer but you posted it as a comment, so it voting was not possible.